# Why has my jQuery suddenly stopped working?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

They were working fine and then something happened that I can't figure out. I've stripped the code down as much as possible but still can't find the problem.
For a while, the datepicker() method was showing only a raw html table of numbers, but now it shows nothing when I click the text box. My stylesheet for the UI's is connected and in the right place. What is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.8.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mydomain.com/lbStyle.css"/>
<script src="http://myDomain.com/index.js"></script>

        <title>
            Welcome to The Bringer Network
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to The Bringer Network</h1>
        <h2>Post A Show You Need Guests For</h2>

        <form id="dialog">

        <p> Date <input type="text" id="date"/></p>
        <p> Name of Show: <input type="text" id="performance" /></p>
         <p> Name of location<input type="text" id="location"/> </p>
         <p> Time <input type="text" id="time"/></p>
         <p>Number of Guests Needed<input type="text" id="guests" /></p>
         <p>Cover Price<input type="text" id="price"/></p> 

         <button>Submit</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>

//JS

$(function(){
   Parse.initialize("Uobn9YUjayFeR****xQ6h", "AxqKDV1P24VSw*****p2QcvhyEXdvW");

    $("button").button();

    $("#date").datepicker();

    $("#dialog").dialog();

});//closes function
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? P.S. you need to include jQuery BEFORE jQuery UI.

Comment: Does `lbStyle.css` include all the jQuery UI CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the jquery-ui library after the jquery library.